# c# Method tooltip doesn't appear in other project

Tags: c#, portable-class-library, summary

I wrote method description in one dll:

```
namespace DriveLibrary.Web {
    public class ParseHtml {
        /// <summary>
        /// Get Absolute URL adress from domain and arbitrary url (absolute or relative).
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="ancor">Absolute or relative URL (&quot;/page.html&quot; or &quot;page.html&quot; or &quot;http://domain.com/page.html&quot;)</param>
        /// <param name="domain">Domain url with or without slash in the end (&quot;http://ya.ru/&quot; or &quot;https://google.com&quot;)</param>
        /// <param name="replaceAmp">Whether replase &quot;&amp;amp;&quot; with &quot;&amp;&quot;</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        static public string GetAbsoluteUrl (string ancor, string domain, bool replaceAmp = true) {
            return "abs url";
        }
    }
}
```

In this project I see all tooltips well.

But from other project after I add this dll (I added link to dll from Debug folder) when I'm writing `ParseHtml.GetAbsoluteUrl` I don't see any description.

Comment: When you copy the dll to the other project, you have to copy the accompanying xml file, that is where VS gets the intellisense information from. The xml file is not needed when you deploy, just for development.

Comment: It could also be that you have not enabled the compiler to output the xml file. Open the dll's project, double-click on Properties, select Build... Near the bottom of the page should be a checkbox labeled XML documentation file: If it is not checked the xml file will not get generated on build of the dll.